# Facebook API login error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

When I'm trying to log in with my facebook button on asp page (jdk) I'm getting this error:

```
App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.
```

I've tried so many solutions available online, but its not working.
So, my login java script is "http://localhost:8003/en/user/login/".
The things that I set on the facebook app are: contact mail, site url:"http://localhost:8003/" 
Valid OAuth redirect URIs "http://localhost:8003/". 
I have set option "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" to yes.

Does anyone have any idea why it isn't working?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you used the right app id?

Comment: Yes, i quadrachecked everything, doesnt find reason why it wont work. Tried to change redirect uris to java script path, i tried even with test app. :/ i tried making new app and it doesnt work either. Only way i made  it work was from a blank page where everything is directly in localhost:port/ not in subfolders

Answer (score 0):

So i made it work. I feel ashamed that it took me soo long to figure it out.
Just had to put javascript for FB login in master page and it is available everywhere on website and localhost:port/ work as valid Valid OAuth redirect URI.